# SnakeYaml Deserialise Class containing a List of Objects

Tags: yaml, snakeyaml

I'm trying to use snakeyaml to deserilise the below YAML into the domain model below, however I keep getting java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to ConfigurableThing.

Note I am able to successfully deserialise a single ConfigurableThing, it's only when trying to deserialise the list of ConfigurableThings that I run into issues.

**Code to deserialise**

```
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("config.yml").getFile());

        try(InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file)){
            Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
            Configuration config = yaml.loadAs(in,Configuration.class);
        }
```

**YAML**

```
things:
 - type: TYPE1
   name: foo
   value: 2.00
 - type: TYPE2
   name: bar
   value 8.00
```

**Model**

```
public final class Config {

    private List<ConfigurableThing> things;

    //Getter and Setter

}

public final class ConfigurableThing {

    private Type type;

    private String name;

    private BigDecimal value;

    //Getters and Setters
}

public enum Type {
    TYPE1,TYPE2
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't show the code you use to load your YAML, but your problem is probably that you did not register the collection type properly. Try this:

```java
Constructor constructor = new Constructor(Config.class);
TypeDescription configDesc = new TypeDescription(Config.class);
configDesc.putListPropertyType("things", ConfigurableThing.class);
constructor.addTypeDescription(configDesc);
Yaml yaml = new Yaml(constructor);
Config config = (Config) yaml.load(/* ... */);
```

The reason why you need to do this is type erasure – SnakeYaml cannot determine the generic parameter of the `List` interface at runtime. So you need to tell it to construct the list items as `ConfigurableThing`; if you do not, a `HashMap` will be constructed. This is what you see in the error message.

Comment: Perfect, Thank You!  For posterity I've added the incorrect code that I was using load YAML.

Comment: Your edit suggestion was right even though people rejected it. `addTypeDescription` is the correct name; the SnakeYaml documentation uses `addTypeDefinition` which is just wrong.

Comment: It works, but just adding a couple of lines,which illustrates a little bit more what is happening in the very last line :File file = new File("configuration.yaml");
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
            Config list = (Config)yaml.load(in);

Comment: @SilverBlaze Since OP added the code loading the YAML, it is evident that it's not loaded from a file, but from a resource, so your code is not applicable to this question. I intentionally left that code out because it is not relevant to the question and even if we assume someone wants to load a file, why should they use your approach instead of `Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("configuration.yaml"))`?

Comment: FWIW the `putListPropertyType()` method has been deprecated.

Comment: @VictorCui Can you elaborate? It is still used in the [official documentation](https://bitbucket.org/snakeyaml/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation) and I can't find information about what should be used instead.